# Надо ли ставить запятую перед частицей «бы»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, частица

Надо ли ставить запятую перед частицей «бы» в предложениях: *Я хотел бы...*?

Answer (score 1):

Запятая в данном случае **не нужна**. Это сослагательное наклонение, и так уж исторически сложилось, что в таких случаях запятая **не ставится**. Например:

> Я хотел бы пойти домой.

Думаю, что исторически так сложилось, что запятая не ставится, потому что...

> нет причин её ставить =)

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец исправил =)

Answer (score 0):

Нет, там не нужна запятая. Но есть различнные конструкции с "бы", которые выделяются запятыми.

Comment: Приведите пример.